# Why UINavigationBar backButton disappear after set its background image in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, background-image, back-button

After I set the backgroundImage for the backButton Image, it will disappear.

But when I clicked it once time, it will appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage *barBackBtnImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackIndicatorImage:barBackBtnImg];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:barBackBtnImg];
```